# Mat-Tooltips in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

How can dynamically show and hide material design tooltips?
I have component which displays tooltips int *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" fxLayout="row">
        <mat-form-field matTooltip="{{item.comment}}">
          <input matInput>
        </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I have button, to handle show/hide toolbars on change, but how to show and hide these toolbars?

In doc there is example using one toolbar:

```
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="tooltip.show()"> Show tooltip </button>

<span matTooltip="This is the tooltip message" #tooltip="matTooltip">
  I have a tooltip
</span>
```

This is easy, but how to deal with multiple tooltips from *ngFor?

Comment: Do you have one button for all, for a button for each tooltip?

Comment: @Vega one button for all tooltips

Comment: How do you distinguish for which one it should pop the tooltip?

Comment: @Vega togling button should show all tooltips at once, and close all tooltips at once. Something like "show/hide comments" if you know what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@ViewChildren` to get a reference to all tooltips. To cancel the default 'behaviour' of tooltips, set disabling `matTooltipDisabled` attribute to a property. That property value should be triggered either by the button click, either on `mousemove` on the `input` caring the tooltip or the wrapping `div`.
You will also need a timeout to counter-clock AM timeout before tooltip is shown.

**Typescript:**

```
import { ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
...
@ViewChildren('tooltip') tooltips;
...
  showAllTooltips() {
    this.show = !this.show;
    if (this.show) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.tooltips._results.forEach(item => item.show())
      }, 5); tooltip pop
    } else {
        this.tooltips._results.forEach(item => item.hide());
    }
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
<div (mousemove)="show=false" *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <mat-form-field [matTooltipDisabled]="!show" matTooltip="{{item.comment}}" #tooltip="matTooltip">
        <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="showAllTooltips()"> Show / hide all tooltips </button>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcvri8-dcqmtd)**

Comment: this look really nice, I will implement this, and if work give you "correct answer"

Comment: do you know any solution to block hiding/showing on hover tooltips? So if I click -> showAllTooltips all tooltips is showed, but when I hover on mat-form tooltips don't hides?

Answer (score 5):

Use Material provided properties to show/hide tool-tips and manage position for those. Show/hide all tool-tips on one click can be achieved with `@ViewChildren`.

```html
<div (mouseover)="tooltipStatus=true" *ngFor="let item of fieldsData; let i=index">
    <mat-form-field 
    [matTooltipDisabled]="!tooltipStatus" 
    matTooltip="{{item.tooltip}}"
    matTooltipPosition='right'
    #tooltip="matTooltip">
    <!-- possible value for position 'above|below|left|right' -->

        <input matInput [value]="item.value">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="toggleTooltips()"> Toggle Tooltips </button>
```

[See code on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tv32ra)